writing multiple data frames into the same excel file in R
first off I have below sample data frames:
a<-(1:10)
b<-(10:19)
c<-(1:10)
d<-(20:29)
df_t1<-data.frame(a,b)
df_t2<-data.frame(c,d)

And then I try to save the 2 data frames into one excel file:
Saving the first one was okay:
write.xlsx(df_t1,file="demo.xlsx",sheetName="sheet1",rowNames=FALSE)


However, when I ran the second line:
write.xlsx(df_t1,file="demo.xlsx",sheetName="sheet2",append=TRUE,rowNames=FALSE)


Instead of adding a new sheet named "sheet 2", it overwrites "sheet1" with "sheet2" even append is set to be TRUE in second line. Any ideas on what went wrong? Cheers.

I acheived it by using write.xlsx from openxlsx. I passed the two dataframes
to the method in a list. write.xlsx from xlsx seems to have issues lately.
a<-(1:10)
b<-(10:19)
c<-(1:10)
d<-(20:29)
df_t1<-data.frame(a,b)
df_t2<-data.frame(c,d)
listOfData <- list("sheet1"=df_t1,"sheet2"=df_t2)
openxlsx::write.xlsx(listOfData,file="demo.xlsx",rowNames=FALSE)


Thanks, wondering if I need to add a new sheet , say "sheet3", rather than updating the list vector, anything i can do about it? Thanks.

openxlsx::write.xlsx() does not have the append argument. You'd have to make a new workbook for each additional sheet.
